# Matrix 1,2,3 how can i generate?

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

i want to control the creation of random numbers in this matrix :

```
Mp = floor(1+(10*rand(2,20)));
mp1 = sort(Mp,2);
```

i want to modify this code in order to have an output like this :

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9 9 10 10 10 10
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7 8 9  9  9  10
```

i have to fill each row with all the numbers going from 1 to 10 in an increasing order and the second matrix that counts the occurences of each number should be like this :

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 4
1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 3 1
```

and the most tricky matrix that i'v been looking for since the last week is the third matrix that should skim through each row of the first matrix and returns the numbers of occurences of each number and the position of the last occcurence.here is an example of how the code should work. this example show the intended result after running through the first row of the first matrix.

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 (positions)
1     2    
2         2
3               3
4                  1
5                      2              
6                         1
7                               2                    
8                                  1
9                                        2
10                                                    4
```

(numbers)

this example show the intended result after running through the second row of the first matrix.

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 (positions)
1   1 2    
2     1   2
3               3 6
4                  1 1
5                      3              
6                         1         4
7                               2      1              
8                                  1     1
9                                        2         3
10                                                    4
```

(numbers)

so the wanted matrix must be filled up with zeros from the beginning and each time after running through each row of the first matrix, we add the new result to the previous one...

Comment: Seems like a very localized problem. Do you care if the code is not super efficient?

Comment: "i want to modify this code in order to have an output like this :" Don't get what you want to modify? Code matches already your output.

Comment: @Sam: You already asked at least a part of this question. What's wrong with the answer you got there? Why are you asking the same again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552147/how-can-i-generate-this-matrix

Comment: How do you want to handle "missing numbers" - which will occur when you draw 20 random numbers from {1,10}.

Comment: @Sam Since you said in comments below that you got what you needed here, could you mark an answer as accepted OR you can post your own answer and accept it.  Either way is acceptable, although I'm partial to my own.  ;)  Otherwise people might come by and keep working on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code does everything you asked for. If I didn't understand, you need to get a lot clearer in how you pose your question...

Note - I hard coded some values / sizes. In "real code" you would never do that, obviously.

```
% the bit of code that generates and sorts the initial matrix:
Mp = floor(1+(10*rand(2,20)));
mp1 = sort(Mp, 2);
clc
disp(mp1)

occCount = zeros(size(mp1));

for ii = 1:size(mp1,1)
    for jj = 1:size(mp1,2)
        if (jj == 1)
            occCount(ii,jj) = 1;
        else
            if (mp1(ii,jj) == mp1(ii,jj-1))
                occCount(ii,jj) = occCount(ii, jj-1) + 1;
            else
                occCount(ii,jj) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

% this is the second matrix you asked for
disp(occCount)

% now the third:
big = zeros(10, 20);
for ii = 1:size(mp1,1)
    for jj = 1:10
        f = find(mp1(ii,:) == jj); % index of all of them
        if numel(f) > 0
            last = f(end);
             n = numel(f);
             big(jj, last) = big(jj, last) + n;
        end
    end
end

disp(big)
```

Please see if this is indeed what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am editing the previous answer to check if it is fast when mp1 is large, and apparently it is:

```
N = 20000; M = 200; P = 100;
mp1 = sort([repmat(1:P, M, 1), ceil(P*rand(M,N-P))], 2);
tic
% Initialise output matrices
out1 = zeros(M, N); out2 = zeros(P, N);
for gg = 1:M
    % Frequencies of each row
    freqs(:, 1) = mp1(gg, [find(diff(mp1(gg, :))), end]);
    freqs(:, 2) = histc(mp1(gg, :), freqs(:, 1));
    cumfreqs = cumsum(freqs(:, 2));
    k = 1;
    for hh = 1:numel(freqs(:, 1))
      out1(gg, k:cumfreqs(hh)) = 1:freqs(hh, 2);
      out2(freqs(hh, 1), cumfreqs(hh)) = out2(freqs(hh, 1), cumfreqs(hh)) + freqs(hh, 2);
      k = cumfreqs(hh) + 1;
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: thank u all guys for your help, your are really beautiful minds and geniuses !! @Daniel R the code that you gave me yesterday works perfectly for the seconde matrix,@Floris your code  perfectly matches what i have in mind and what i'v explained.  Still got a problem with first matrix

Comment: the first matrix should have random numbers in an increasing order starting always with 1 and finishing always with 10 and generating all numbers between 1 and 10. the code above generates random numbers but sometimes it starts with number 2 and jumps directly to number 4 without generating number 3. the problem here is that i want to control the random generator so that can fullfill what i want

Comment: an example of a row of the first matrix :                                              1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10

Comment: Sam, that is not possible. Random numbers are random - so you can't be sure that all numbers from 1 to 10 will be actually extracted. What you can do is this: mp1 = sort([repmat(1:10, 2, 1), floor(1+(10*rand(2,10)))], 2); but then you only have 10 random numbers, not 20.

Comment: i took a combination of all codes here and modified them in order to create something that fits my work,now my simulation is working awesomely. You saved my life, and you made me save a lot of time.Everyone here deserves a medal. Peace for you all !

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves both the second and third matrix generation problems with a single loop.  For clarity, the second matrix `M2` is the `2-by-20` array in the example containing the cumulative occurrence count. The third matrix `M3` is the sparse matrix of size `10-by-20` in the example that encodes the number and position of the last occurrence of each unique value.  The code only loops over the rows, using `accumarray` to do most of the work. It is generalized to any size and content of `mp1`, as long as the rows are sorted first.

```
% data
mp1 = [1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9 9 10 10 10 10;
       1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7 8 9  9  9  10]; % the example first matrix
nuniq = max(mp1(:));

% accumulate
M2 = zeros(size(mp1));
M3 = zeros(nuniq,size(mp1,2));

for ir=1:size(mp1,1),
    cumSums = accumarray(mp1(ir,:)',1:size(mp1,2),[],@numel,[],true)';
    segments = arrayfun(@(x)1:x,nonzeros(cumSums),'uni',false);
    M2(ir,:) = [segments{:}];
    countCoords = accumarray(mp1(ir,:)',1:size(mp1,2),[],@max,[],true);
    [ii,jj] = find(countCoords);
    nzinds = sub2ind(size(M3),ii,nonzeros(countCoords));
    M3(nzinds) = M3(nzinds) + nonzeros(cumSums);
end
```

I won't print the outputs because they are a bit big for the answer, and the code is runnable as is.

NOTE: For new test data, I suggest using the commands `Mp = randi(10,[2,20]); mp1 = sort(Mp,2);`.  Or based on your request to user2875617 and his response, ensure all numbers with `mp1 = sort([repmat(1:10,2,1) randi(10,[2,10])],2);` but that isn't really random...

**EDIT: Error in code fixed.**